# Vignette like function from 0 (at the edge) to 1 (in the center) that doesn't have sharp corners

Tags: function, math

I have a picture with normalized coordinates ((-1, -1), in the top left corner, (0, 0) in the center, (1, 1) in  the bottom right) and i want an function to output a 0 at the corners and a 1 in the center. I have tried some `f(x,y) = 1 - max(abs(x), abs(y))` but that produces sharp corners:

[image]

What function produces a more round output, rather than this pyramid-like function?

Comment: What do you mean by "more round output"?

Comment: Without the sharp edges where abs(x)==abs(y)

Comment: This is very subjective

Comment: That being said, I've posted an answer ...

Comment: Dont forget to select an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is using the squared distance to the origin.  A smoother version would use the distance itself.  Also note that your formula `-(1/sqrt(2)*x)**2-(1/sqrt(2)*y)**2 + 1` can be simplified to `1 - (x**2 + y**2) / 2`.

Here is a comparison between the squared distance (at the left), the distance itself (at the center) and one of the formulas proposed by @MadPhysicist (at the right). The image is made a bit larger to better illustrate what's happening near the borders. A contour plot is used to show how the values are smoothed out:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

k = 1.2
x, y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-k, k, 100), np.linspace(-k, k, 100))

sqrt2 = np.sqrt(2)
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=3, figsize=(12, 6))
for i, axrow in enumerate(axes):
    for j, ax in enumerate(axrow):
        if j == 0:
            f = -(1 / sqrt2 * x) ** 2 - (1 / sqrt2 * y) ** 2 + 1  # f =  1 - (x**2 + y**2) / 2
        elif j == 1:
            f = 1 - np.sqrt(x * x + y * y) / sqrt2
        else:
            s = 0.65
            f = np.exp(-0.5 * (np.sqrt(x * x + y * y) / s) ** 2)
        img = ax.imshow(f, cmap='Greys_r', extent=[-k, k, -k, k], vmin=0, vmax=1)
        if i == 0:
            img = ax.contour(x, y, f, levels=np.linspace(0, 1, 11), cmap='inferno_r')
        ax.axhline(1, color='red', ls=':')
        ax.axhline(-1, color='red', ls=':')
        ax.axvline(1, color='red', ls=':')
        ax.axvline(-1, color='red', ls=':')
        plt.colorbar(img, ax=ax)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: comparison plot]

Comment: It's nice to keep the square root in the parentheses conceptually, because it represents the scaling of the value at the corners.

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't seem to be concerned with unbounded drop-off along the edges, a parabola is definitely one possible option, as you discovered. In fact any monotonic function can be used to generate a "cone" of that type, by applying it to the radius:

```
f(r) = 1 - r/sqrt(2)
r = sqrt(x^2 + y^2)
```

This gives a linear cone. Your answer is equivalent to

```
f(r) = 1 - (r/sqrt(2))^2
```

You can increase the power of `r` all you want to get similar results, with a more spread-out central region and sharper drop-offs. Taking powers smaller than one will sharpen the peak in the center.

A more typical function to use in this case would be a Gaussian. You would not necessarily have zeros in the corners, but this is a ubiquitous function you should probably know about:

```
f(r) = exp(-0.5*(r/s)^2)
```

Here `s`, the standard deviation of the spread, determines the width of the peak.

Answer (score 0):

Found it. I had to use a quadratic equation like this:

`f(x,y)=-(1/sqrt(2)*x)**2-(1/sqrt(2)*y)**2 + 1`

That produces a nice vignette like this

[image]

Comment: Yes, x^2 + y^2 = r^2 is the equation of a circle with radius r about the origin. I don't get the labelling of the axes, though. The origin should be at the centre!

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand. Those are just matplotlib pixel coordinates. The origin is at the center and the corners are at +/-1, +/-1, as stated in the question